# Python/Django Class based saving

Tags: python, javascript, jquery, security, django

I'm creating multiple Django apps with vote possibilities, so I made an app `vote` to handle all this votes. In my templates I'm including an ajax-function named `vote`. To know on which model I'm liking I add `app_name` and `model_name` to the `vote` function (I made some templatetags to get these values). In my views.py I use `model = apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)` to get the model class. But now I'm worried a hacker could do something with the `app_name` and `model_name` values.

### vote/ajax.html (only function):

```
function vote(bool){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        timeout: 8000,
        url: '{% url 'ajax:vote' %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
            'model_name': "{{ model|get_model_name }}",
            'app_name': "{{ model|get_app_name }}",
            'voted': bool,
            'id': "{{ model.id }}",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.error){
                if (bool){
                    $(".half .fa-thumbs-up").removeClass("far").addClass("fas");
                    $(".half #count").text(parseInt($(".half #count").text()) + 1);
                } else {
                    $(".half .fa-thumbs-down").removeClass("far").addClass("fas");
                    $(".half #count").text(parseInt($(".half #count").text()) - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### ajax/views.py:

```
def vote(request):
    try:
        app_name = request.POST.get("app_name")
        model_name = request.POST.get("model_name")
        id = request.POST.get("id")
        votedFor = True if request.POST.get("voted") == "true" else False
    except ValueError:
        return JsonResponse({"error": True})

    model = apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)

    if model is None or id is None:
        return JsonResponse({"error": True})

    try:
        usable_model = model.objects.get(id=id)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": True})

    try:
        usable_model.vote._meta.get_field("votes")
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": True})

    usable_model.vote.vote(request, votedFor)
    return JsonResponse({"error": False})
```

### vote/functions:

```
def vote(self, request, votedFor):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if not UserVoted.objects.filter(User=request.user, Vote=self).exists():
            UserVoted.objects.create(User=request.user, Vote=self, votedFor=votedFor)
            self._like_or_dislike(votedFor)
            return True
        return False
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    if ip:
        if not UserVoted.objects.filter(ip=ip, Vote=self).exists():
            UserVoted.objects.create(ip=ip, Vote=self, votedFor=votedFor)
            self._like_or_dislike(votedFor)
            return True
        return False
    return False

def _like_or_dislike(self, votedFor):
    if votedFor is not None:
        Vote.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(votes=F('votes') + 1) if votedFor else Vote.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(votes=F('votes') - 1)
        return True
    return False
```

I already manipulated `app_name` and `model_name` and the server didn't crash but I don't know what a hacker can do. Can he crash my server when he manipulate these values? (maybe "ajax-injection" or something like this?)

Comment: Your indentation is off. This being Python, indentation is very important. Remove your code, paste it in file-by-file and with every bit you paste in, select it, hit Ctrl + K. The question editor should do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question

> But now I'm worried a hacker could do something with the `app_name` and `model_name` values.
>
> Can he crash my server when he manipulate these values? (maybe "ajax-injection" or something like this?)

I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be. Perhaps it would be wise to define a list of the values that are acceptable for a user to pass there, though maybe that wouldn't be sufficient.

### Other review points

> ```
> function vote(bool){
> ```

The name `bool` is not very descriptive. Given that it is used as the value for the `voted` parameter a name like `voted` would be more appropriate. And if your code complies with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) standards you could simply write
    voted

in the list of parameters as a shorthand for `voted: voted`

---

The success handler looks like this:

> ```
> success: function(data) {
>     if (!data.error){
>         if (bool){
>             $(".half .fa-thumbs-up").removeClass("far").addClass("fas");
>             $(".half #count").text(parseInt($(".half #count").text()) + 1);
>         } else {
>             $(".half .fa-thumbs-down").removeClass("far").addClass("fas");
>             $(".half #count").text(parseInt($(".half #count").text()) - 1);
>         }
> ```

There is quite a bit of redundancy in both cases. Also `parseInt()` calls should pass a radix<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)</sup>.

```
if (!data.error){
    const thumbClass = '.fa-thumbs-' + bool ? 'up' : 'down';
    $(".half " + thumbClass).removeClass("far").addClass("fas");
    const toAdd = bool ? 1 : -1;
    $(".half #count").text(parseInt($(".half #count").text(), 10) + toAdd);
```

---

In the `vote` function in ajax/views.py there is this line:

> ```
> votedFor = True if request.GET.get("voted") == "true" else False
> ```

This could be simplified to just:

```
votedFor = request.GET.get("voted") == "true"
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix</sub>

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer for my old question, that isn`t very common! I already found a better way. I register all models in a global dict by saving the model class with a random ID. In the frontend then I use the ID and send it, in the backend I then can easily get the model by the ID.